# Angular query params as boolean type, not string

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to pass a query parameter to an `*ngIf` but this keep evaluating to true due to being a string type. How do I change my query parameter to a boolean so it will evaluate as false?

The query param is `?paywall=true` but is still true with the query `?paywall=false`

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.paywallQuery$ = this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('paywall')));
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="(paywallQuery$ | async)"> <-- always evaluates as true
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Map the value to a boolean by performing a string comparison against `'true'`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.paywallQuery$ = this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
    map(params => {
      const value = params.get('paywall');
      return value ? value.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' : false;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I already depend on Angular's CDK I would use the boolean coercion function (`coerceBooleanProperty`) to convert that string to a proper boolean.

It's pretty bare bones, but this is the thing with urls and attributes in the web component space vs using javascript to do the binding.
`queryparams`, `pathparams`, and `attributes` are all string values so you gotta convert them for them to make sense in your implementation.

This would be my code:

```
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
this.paywallQuery = coerceBooleanProperty(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('paywall'))
```

and you can see some examples here:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.spec.ts

Comment: This seems a more proper way than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the parameters using JSON.parse. The boolean string value will become a real boolean.

Full code:

```js
export class Page implements OnInit {
  public paywallQuery: boolean;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.paywallQuery = this.getPayWallValueFromQueryParams();
  }

  private getQueryParams() {
    return this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
  }

  private getPayWallValueFromQueryParams(): boolean {
    return JSON.parse(this.getQueryParams().paywall);
  }
}
```

Note: I used the snapshot instead of the observable query params, therefore:

```html
<div *ngIf="paywallQuery"></div>
```