# How hide element with url get parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application written in Angular 13 using Typescript.

I want to hide items with get url parameters and set it to true if it doesn't exist.

```js
export class AppComponent {

  menu: boolean = true;

  constructor(private oauthService: InitialAuthService, private userRoleService: UserRoleService, private route: ActivatedRoute,) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params: any) => {

        this.menu = !!params["menu"] ? params["menu"] : true

      }
    );
    this.menu = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['menu'];
```

I simply want to cache HTML element following parameters obtained in URL.

For example

```
http://localhost:4200/index?menu=false   // hide menu 
http://localhost:4200/index?menu=true    // show menu 
http://localhost:4200/index              // show menu
```

html side

```js
<div *ngIf="menu">...</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? What exactly is not working as you expect?

Comment: Please provide more information. Is something not working as expected, or what's the problem?

Comment: it's more clearer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular query params as boolean type, not string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999267/angular-query-params-as-boolean-type-not-string)

Comment: it's  not problem of String

Comment: I don't know if it may be because the menu and the main component I need this for all routing router-outlet

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  isShown$!: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._handleRouteQueryParams();    
  }

  private _handleRouteQueryParams(): void {
    this.isShown$ = this.route
      .queryParamMap
      .pipe(map(params => {
        return !params.has('menu') || params.get('menu') === 'true';
    }));
  }
}
```

In the template

```
<div *ngIf="isShown$ | async">...</div>
```

Comment: think it's work